# Scala - two operand or/and functions

Tags: scala

In Java there are static and/or functions which receive two boolean operands and return the correct result: `logicalAnd` and `logicalOr` (both located in `java.lang.Boolean`) [1]:

```
public static boolean logicalAnd(boolean a, boolean b)
public static boolean logicalOr(boolean a, boolean b)
```

I'm looking for a similar concept in the Scala standard library. Is there any?

### Edit

I know Scala can call Java functions, but this code won't compile since Java's functions are not high-order, so it's not usable for me:

```
val op =
  if (input == "or") java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr
  else java.lang.Boolean.logicalAnd
```

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use a function literal:

```
val op: (Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean =
  if (input == "or")
    _ || _
  else
    _ && _
```

Answer (score 4):

The fact that

```
val op =
  if (input == "or") java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr
  else java.lang.Boolean.logicalAnd
```

doesn't compile has nothing to do with those methods being defined in Java or in Scala.

The code you posted actually compiles in Scala 3. In Scala 2 you have to be explicit when you want to turn a method into a function value:

```
val op =
  if (input == "or") java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr _
  else java.lang.Boolean.logicalAnd _
```

Comment: Explicitly saying that you want `op` to be a `(Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean` also works: `val op: (Boolean, Boolean) => Boolean = if (input == "or") java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr else java.lang.Boolean.logicalAnd`

Comment: Yes if the expected type is a function type you don't need to explicitly convert the method. But in that case I would definitely go with `_ && _` instead of `Boolean.logicalAnd`.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, you can avoid using these methods in lambda processing, using the `_` syntax and the bitwise operators:

- Boolean::logicalAnd => `_ & _`
- Boolean::logicalOr => `_ | _`

For example, if you have in Java something like this:

```
Stream.of(/* .. some objects .. */)
      .map(/* some function that returns a boolean */)
      .reduce(Boolean::logicalOr);
```

In Scala is possible to write using `_` syntax:

```
LazyList.fill(/* ... */)
     .map(/* ... */)
     .reduce(_ & _) // or | or ^
```

Comment: The Java alternative is not good enough. For example, this won't compile: `val op = if (input == "or") java.lang.Boolean.logicalOr else java.lang.Boolean.logicalAnd` since Java's functions are not high-order functions. I'll update the question

Comment: Oh right I am sorry :) do you agree with me on the second part though? I would say that you can use bitwise operators without any problem, wouldn't you?

Comment: @gianlucaaguzzi Bitwise operators will work here since both function arguments will be evaluated before the operators do their work, but other than here, it's usually better to use the short-circuiting `&&` and `||`.